# If derivative of function is less than or equal to 4, prove the existence of point $c$ so $f(c)=c^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am struggling to construct a simple proof of the following.

Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable for any real value $x$ and that $f'(x) \le 4$ for all real values of x. Prove there is at most one real value $c>2$ such that $f(c) =c^2$.

I am completely lost on where to start on this proof and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your heading doesn't match the text.  Are you trying to prove existence or uniqueness or both?

Comment: Note:  the function $f(x)=x$ is a counterexample to the text question (as $f(0)=0^2$ and $f(1)=1^2$).  Maybe the text was meant to read "at LEAST one real value..."

Comment: @lulu $0$ and $1$ are not values satisfying $c>2$.

Comment: @ClementC.  Ah, missed that condition.  Thanks!

Comment: Assume that there are more than $1$ value of such $c$. Then they both lie on the curve $y=x^2$ for $x>2$, and in particular since $x^2$ is convex the gradient of line connecting those two points is greater than $4$. Then use MVT on $f$ for these two points to show that there exists a point $x_0$ between these two points such that $f'(x_0)>4$.

Answer (score 3):

Say there were two such values $f(a)=a^2$, $f(b)=b^2$ with $a,b>2$ (we will obtain a contradiction) Then the slope of the chord connecting those two points on the graph is $$m=\frac {b^2-a^2}{b-a}=b+a$$

As $a,b>2$ we see that $m>4$.  Now, the MVT tells us that there is some value $t\in [a,b]$ with $f'(t)=m>4$.  But this contradicts our assumption on the derivative, so we are done.

Comment: How would I prove this with the condition that there is at most one such point that f(c)=c^2?

Comment: Sorry, not following.  I was working by contradiction.  I assumed (with intent of disproving) that there were two such points.  I then derived a contradiction from that assumption (specifically, I used the two solutions plus the MVT to show that the derivative had to be greater than $4$ somewhere).